# Can function template use map parameters？

Tags: function, templates, dictionary, parameters

I have a set of data type like this:

```
map<Type, SubComponent*>.
```

And I want to do similar opration to them, so I think about using funciton template like this:

```
template< typename Type, typename SubComponent >
void DeleteSubComponents( map<Type, SubComponent*> &subComponentMap )
{
    for( map<Type, SubComponent*>::iterator it=subComponentMap.begin();
         it!=subComponentMap.end(); ++it ){
        if( NULL != it->second ){
            delete it->second;
            it->second = NULL;
        }
    }
    subComponentMap.clear();

    return;
}
```

But it doesn't compile sussesfully with error:

```
line 967:  error: dependent-name ‘std::map<Type,SubComponent*,std::less<_Key>,std::allocator<std::pair<const Type, SubComponent*> > >::iterator’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
line 967: note: say ‘typename std::map<Type,SubComponent*,std::less<_Key>,std::allocator<std::pair<const Type, SubComponent*> > >::iterator’ if a type is meant
```

I have no idea about this, Can function template use map parameters？ Thanks!